# Nonstrict inequality in the proof involving the notion of distance between an element and a set in the real line

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

I am studying a proof in Searcoid's Metric Spaces that:
$$\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le|z-\Bbb{sup}(S)|\Bbb{\,with\,equality\,if\,}z\ge\Bbb{sup}(S)$$
where $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ and $z\in\Bbb{R}$.

Let both supremum and infimum of $S$ be real. Consider the case when $s=\Bbb{sup}(S)\le z$, we set out to prove the equality above.

First the author let $t$ be an arbitrary positive real number. Since $s=\Bbb{sup}(S)$, the intersection $(s-t,s]\cap S$ is nonempty (or else $s$ wouldn't be the least upper bound of set $S$), so that $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le z-s+t$. And since $t$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le z-s$.

My question is the nonstrict inequality sign in the inequality: $$\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\color{red}{\le} z-s+t=z-(s-t) \tag{1}$$

Since $t$ is a positive number, there is always a "gap" between the supremum $s$ and $s-t$, therefore there is no way for $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)$ to be equal to $z-s+t$, even in the best case of $z=s$ when $z$ is the closest to $s-t$. I understand that as $a\le b$ means either $a<b$ or $a=b$ is true, the statement above is technically true, even when the case $a=b$ turns out to be false. However, I think that since $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)= z-s+t$ $\mathbf{cannot}$ happen, the author should $\mathbf{not}$ use nonstrict inequality sign but strict inequality sign instead. But if the author chose to use strict inequality sign, then we wouldn't be led to the conclusion above, and this will complicate the remaining effort.

I suspect there is some hole in my reasoning which makes me fail to see the nonstrict inequality above. I understand intuitively that $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le z-s$ by the means of crude geometric argument (i.e.:  drawing the real line and labelling the variable involved) but I would like to understand the inequality $(1)$ above as it is the essential penultimate step that leads to $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le z-s$.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably just preference. Writing the inequality in $(1)$ as strict or non-strict doesn't affect the conclusion.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I tried to use strict inequality in (1) so I got $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)< z-s+t$. But with the strict less than sign, I couldn't get $\Bbb{dist}(z,S)\le z-s$ as it is not generally true that if for all arbitrary positive real $t$ that $a<b+t$, then $a\le b$ ...

Comment: so what is bothering you? if a-b<t holds for arbitrary t>0 then a-b is either negative or 0.

Comment: @sb945 thank you so much for the explanation. I hate to admit but I had failed to see that